# Select from table where td does not contain a

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a table containing table rows, these table rows contain table data.
Some of the table data fields contain a link.

I want all table rows to be clickable, the user will get another page presented, when clicking on a table row. This behaviour is already working, but the user shouldn't be redirected to another page, when a link within a table data field has been clicked.

I'm currently using following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table tr:has(td)").click(function () {
            var idForRow = $($($(this).find('td').get(0)).find('input[type=hidden]').get(0)).val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("jsDetails", "Company", new { id = "REPLACEME"})'
            window.location.href = url.replace('REPLACEME', idForRow);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to exclude all `td's` that contain an `a` tag.
The line I think we should be editing is:

```
$("table tr:has(td)").click(function () {
```

This line now only filters out table rows that don't contain a table data field, since they aren't relevant.
I think using the `not()` function could provide me a solution, but I can't get the syntax right. I tried:

```
$("table tr:has(td) td:not(a)").click(function () {
```

But the code still reaches the next line.

My View:

```
@using MemoMelder.HtmlHelpers;
@model MemoMelder.Models.CompanyListViewModel
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Companies";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Companies</h2>

<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Companies)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CompanyId)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.SimpleLink(item.WebsiteUrl, "Website", "_blank")
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { item.CompanyId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs", @role = "button" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { item.CompanyId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs", @role = "button" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { item.CompanyId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs", @role = "button" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Question**

Following line:

```
$("table tr:has(td)").click(function () {
```

Should be modified, so that the click function isn't called, when a table data field that contains a has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not` with `:has` selector:

```
$("table tr:not(:has(a))").click(function () {
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xaxuzvdb/)**

**Update:** by targetting td elements as you suggested.

```
$("table td:not(:has(a))").click(function () { 
 var idForRow =$($($(this).parent().find('td').get(0)).find('input[type=hidden]').get(0)).val(); 
 alert(idForRow); 
 var url = '@Url.Action("jsDetails", "Company", new { id = "REPLACEME"})' 
 window.location.href = url.replace('REPLACEME', idForRow); 
});
```

Comment: So it is correct, that the link is clicked and opens in another page, but now it doesn't fire the code in function when clicking a `td` without `a`.

Comment: The strange thing is that, `idForRow` isn't filled with the first td's value, what did work in the first place. It remains undefined now. Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: @Max: what exactly are you trying to do?? do you want all inner hidden input elements value in array for clicked tr??

Comment: If the row is clicked, doesn't matter what `td` except for a `td` containing an `a` the CompanyId gets retrieved from the hiddenfield in the first td of the table row. This gets send to the controller, when at the controller, it will grab the company and show a detail view. This shouldn't happen if an `a` has been clicked. It only needs to show the website of the clicked url.

Comment: @Max: can you reproduce the problem in above fiddle??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xaxuzvdb/6/ the ID gets retrieved on the old line of code, not at the new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59722/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-max).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$("table tr:has(td) td:not(:has(a))").click(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger on tds but not on hrefs inside td's:

```
    $("table td").filter(function(i,e) {   
    return !$(e).find("a").length })  
.click(function() { alert('this is td click'); });
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8rg1nd0f/**